# React - How can I align the glyphicon to the most right?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

My React App has the autocomplete, in the autocomplete I provide the list and the glyphicon then if I click glyphicon the content will be inserted to the MongoDB.

Anyway, I try to align the glyphicon to the most right but I cannot do that. If I move it outside li, the syntax is error.

The following is the capture image.
[image]

The glyphicon is closed to the text but it should be at the right most.

My code is as following:

```
<li key={_id}>{itemname}
  <i className="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" onClick={() => 
  this.addToReceiving(
    itemid, 
    barcode, 
    itemname, 
    category, 
    stocktype, 
    itemtype, 
    wholesaleprice, 
    retailprice, 
    quantitystock, 
    receivingquantity, 
    description, 
    comment)}>
  </i>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use flexbox to align the items.

add a span to the text

```
<li key={_id}>
  <span>{itemname}</span>
  <i className="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" onClick={() => 
  this.addToReceiving(
    itemid, 
    barcode, 
    itemname, 
    category, 
    stocktype, 
    itemtype, 
    wholesaleprice, 
    retailprice, 
    quantitystock, 
    receivingquantity, 
    description, 
    comment)}>
  </i>
</li>
```

try this : -

```
li {
  display: flex;
  //This will push both child elements to far corner
  //You can also try justify-content: space-around; if you want some space in the corner
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]You can add span or label to the itemname...

Something like this {itemname} or

{itemname}

and add a class item-label ..

.item-label{
  padding-right:10px
}

Hope this helps.